# Why does this formula work for probability of success?

Tags: probability

I need help understanding some probability stuff in a basic intuitive way, because I don't understand what part of the formula represents what.

The question is as follows (video game context): You have a material $m$ and you use it to craft/create an item. The creation itself is always $100\%.$

When you are creating the item, you have a $25\%$ chance of getting $m$ back. If you don't get it back, you can instead fail the item/not complete and have a $90\%$ chance of getting $m$ back.

Now what is the average amount of items made from 1 copy of $m$?

What I know is that this is represented by the formula, or what my friend calls the "closed form?" of $\frac{10p}{1-p}$ and results in $3.33$ for $p = 0.25$. But what I don't get is WHY this formula works, and how does it represent the problem?

I.e. What does $\frac{1}{1-p}$ represent, and why do we multiply it by $10$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be the probability of getting $m$ back. Let $E$ be the expected number of items you make.

With probability $p$ you make 1 item and, since you have $m$ back, you expect to make another $E$ items.

With probability $(1-p)$ x $0.1$ you don't complete and lose $m$.

With probability $(1-p)$ x $0.9$ you don't complete but have $m$ back and so expect to make another $E$ items.

The expected number of items made, $E$, therefore satisfies the equation $$E= p(1+E)+0.9(1-p)E.$$

This simplifies to $E=\frac{10p}{1-p}$ as given by your friend.

Comment: This is almost perfect, but I am slightly still lost on why we do $p(1+E)$ and not just $p$?

Comment: The $p(1+E)$ comes from line 2 of the solution.  Is that what you don't understand?

Comment: Yes, I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how that line translates to that equation essentially. Rest I understand now thanks to you.

Comment: This case occurs with probability $p$. In this case you have made 1 item but because you get $m$ back, you are now in the same position as you started in. You therefore expect to make the same number as you originally expected i.e. $E$. Thus making $1+E$ altogether.

Comment: This is the power of this method - to reproduce the initial situation and use 'recursion'.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it! Thank you. :)